# Flutter Just Audio Error on await _player.setAudioSource(_playlist);

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio, audio-service

I am facing issue with just_audio, when I set comment `await _player.setAudioSource(_playlist);` this line, the app started opening, but when I want to use to set playlist then app get crashed every time.

Version

```
 just_audio: ^0.9.29
 audio_service: ^0.18.7
```

Previously it was working fine, at sudden stoped working. On Mi device no error log printed but on Samsung it shows the error that is pasted with this the question:

> E/AndroidRuntime(29193): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193): Process: com.myapp.music, PID: 29193
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual
> method buildOrThrow()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap; in class
> Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap$Builder; or its super classes
> (declaration of 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder'
> appears in
> /data/app/~~w8o-YhL68Tea9ikpfdER9g==/com.myapp.music-Tng-aVz190Pc8uM2piHH8g==/base.apk!classes21.dex)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioCapabilities.(AudioCapabilities.java:75)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink$Builder.(DefaultAudioSink.java:267)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory.buildAudioSink(DefaultRenderersFactory.java:615)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory.createRenderers(DefaultRenderersFactory.java:294)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.(ExoPlayerImpl.java:240)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer$Builder.build(ExoPlayer.java:1053)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> com.ryanheise.just_audio.AudioPlayer.ensurePlayerInitialized(AudioPlayer.java:736)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> com.ryanheise.just_audio.AudioPlayer.onMethodCall(AudioPlayer.java:410)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown
> Source:12) E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) E/AndroidRuntime(29193):
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) E/AndroidRuntime(29193):
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
> E/AndroidRuntime(29193):        at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
> I/Process (29193): Sending signal. PID: 29193 SIG: 9
>
> to device.Lost connection

Please help…

Comment: Bugs need to be reported on GitHub. Your stack trace also appears to be incomplete, so if there is more to the stack trace, please include it when submitting your bug report.

Comment: Yes sure, let me get that again.